# As a prefix for a service's username, are both "iam" and "its" acceptable?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

Assume a username for a service, for example, this site.

If my name is Alice, but Alice is already a registered username, what would be more correct? "iamAlice" or "itsAlice"?

I think I have never seen the former in the wild, while I have seen a few using the latter variant. For example, a coworker uses "itsBob" both in Telegram and Twitter.

So, my question is rather, is "iam" acceptable in this context? Or should I assume the same rules as when speaking over the phone, that we usually say, "it's Alice" instead of "I'm Alice"?

Comment: Your current username is *user390748*. Is that "correct"? Well, according to so-called correct grammar, it's a name so it should start with uppercase "U".  There is no right or wrong for usernames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A friend of mine uses the "iam" prefix to her name, as a social media username.

Since it is a username, however, it doesn't matter which you use (or even something not related to your name), as long as it is not already in use or prohibited by the service's rules.

Comment: but I mean, from the point of view of "a correct usage of the English language", it's one preferred over the other? Is it one ("iam" in this case) even incorrect at all according to English rules?

Comment: On the phone, yes, we usually would say "it's Alice" instead of "I'm Alice", and you could choose to follow the same convention for a username. However, there's nothing grammatically wrong with "I'm Alice" or "I am Alice". Even on the phone, there are different conventions. Some may say, "Hello, Alice here". I used to work at a company where people would answer the phone and say "Alice Welsh" (just their name).

Comment: *but I mean, from the point of view of "a correct usage of the English language"* The guidance for English is "You may choose **any** name you wish - capitalisation, grammar, the use of punctuation marks, and/or numbers does not matter at all." Names are names - there are no rules. The sentences "I am Alice" and "It is Alice" are both equally correct.

Comment: @auspicious99 Actually, if on the phone, we would say ***this is*** *Alice* much more commonly than either *it's Alice* or *I'm Alice*, both of which would be unnatural.

Comment: Thanks @JasonBassford Oh yes, "this is Alice", you are right, though some in my circle say, "Hey, it's Rob", or "It's Patrick" .. but these days I mostly hear "hi dear" from my wife, and there are others who don't even introduce themselves since most people have caller ID these days